# How to optimize the query? What i could to read, for understand it? (in russian if you can, or english)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, explain

Now my MYSQL query is below.

But in 700 projects, 50 params and 12000 projectparams. foreign keys created, but what indexes to create - i dont know :( the query takes 45+ seconds. It is too big, as i read on some forums, even if i want make it in CRON every 5 minutes.

How to optimize that query? and what indexes i want to create? and how to understand that process? Thanks.

```
  SELECT
        `tt1`.`id` `projects_id`,
        `tt2`.`projectparams_id`,
        `tt2`.`defaultvalue`,
        `tt2`.`defaultvaluealias`,
        `tt2`.`globalvalue`,
        `tt2`.`globalvaluealias`,
        `tt2`.`value`,
        `tt2`.`valuealias`
    FROM
        `projects` `tt1`
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            `t1`.`id` `projectparams_id`,
            `t1`.`defaultvalue`,
            `t1`.`defaultvaluealias`,
            `t1`.`globalvalue`,
            `t1`.`globalvaluealias`,
            `t2`.`value`,
            `t2`.`valuealias`,
            `t2`.`projects_id`
        FROM
            `projectparams` `t1`
        LEFT JOIN `projects_projectparams` `t2` ON `t2`.`projectparams_id` = `t1`.`id`
    ) tt2 ON `tt1`.`id` = `tt2`.`projects_id`
```

Comment: what index i need to create? i dont create that big queries (in 8 millions situations) earlier.

Comment: give index to column which datatype is `int`..

Comment: Basically all the columns used in join conditions, like `id`, `projects_id` should be indexed. To understand the importance of indexing, just google it. There are many tutorails to explain it. Also there would be some youtube videos to do so.

Comment: now my navicat auto create indexes for all foreign keys - index for ID, index for PROJECTS_ID, and index for PROJECTPARAMS_ID. Need more?

Comment: BTW: You would gain readability by removing all the ugly ` which are not needed at all and by using readable aliases, such as `p` for `projects` and `pp` for `projectparams` for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your comments to PaulF's answer it shows you were not only looking for a query optimization, but for another query really. You don't want *all products* with or without specific parameters, but *all possible combinations* of products and parameters.

You should have made this a new request.

Here is the query to get all project / parameter combinations along with the actual project parameters:

```
select
  p.id as projects_id,
  pp.id projectparams_id,
  pp.defaultvalue,
  pp.defaultvaluealias,
  pp.globalvalue,
  pp.globalvaluealias,
  ppp.value,
  ppp.valuealias
from projects p
cross join projectparams pp 
left join projects_projectparams ppp on ppp.projects_id = p.id 
                                     and ppp.projectparams_id = pp.id;
```

Answer (score 5):

As well as the indexes - can you reorganise the query to remove the inner subquery something like :

```
SELECT
  `tt1`.`id` `projects_id`,
  `t1`.`id` `projectparams_id`,
  `t1`.`defaultvalue`,
  `t1`.`defaultvaluealias`,
  `t1`.`globalvalue`,
  `t1`.`globalvaluealias`,
  `t2`.`value`,
  `t2`.`valuealias`
FROM `projects` `tt1` 
LEFT JOIN `projects_projectparams` `t2` ON `tt1`.`id` = `t2`.`projects_id`
LEFT JOIN `projectparams` `t1` ON `t2`.`projectparams_id` = `t1`.`id`
```

Comment: Now the query is: https://i.gyazo.com/607b362efe7b2006af50e928277441f1.png
still take 15 seconds (-35, very good, but 15 sec is normally?)

Comment: Try doing an EXPLAIN - see if that shows what the query is doing

Comment: Yes that's normal. PaulF's query is perfect. You should have indexes on all IDs used, because these should be primary and foreign keys in your tables. If for some reason this isn't the case then do it now.

Comment: I tried to use explain, the mysql man is too dificult for me to understand. Maybe you have some videos or article? explain giving me the table as a request, i am seeing on that table and understanding, that i'm damned stupid moron :(

Comment: So my end query is:
https://i.gyazo.com/5259fbb1123e15915d137bd8caaad7d4.png
still take a lot of time.
I need to find mistake in my logic.

I need to get ALL PROJECTS WITH ALL PARAMS (what have default values) WITH ALL ASSIGNED PARAMS.

Maybe a best practice is filter by several params without giving all? or another propositions?

Comment: @gzhegow: I just looked at your queries in those pngs. How did you come up with that??? Why didn't you use PaulF's query? Why are you doing a cross join??? A cross join gives you combinations, i.e. prod1/prod1, prod1/prod2, prod1/prod3, prod2/prod1, prod2/prod2, ... You cannot want that!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I was just wondering that myself & about to comment, as the original query has no cross join

Comment: Ah, I think I see it now. gzhegow wants all combinations of projects (`projects` table) and parameters (`projectparams` table) and then join the actual paramaters (`projects_projectparams` table). Their query is only lacking a condition on the projects ID then: `ON t2.projectparams_id = t1.id AND t2.projects_id = t0.id`. But this no longer means optimizing the original query but changing it altogether.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I was confused by that at first, but now I have seen your answer I understand - it's much easier to read now too

Comment: Yay, the initial query produces 700 x 12,000 = 8,4M rows, which is not necessary at all. It should return something like 700 x 50 = 35,000 rows at the most, which would only take a few milliseconds if indexes are applied. The solution by @thorsten-kettner should do it.

Comment: @friedemann_bach: I did think about reordering the joins but assumed as the query is simple the join optimizer would sort that - though I know sometimes that doesn't work right - so hoping to see the results of the EXPLAIN. But turns out the original query was wrong anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create indexes first on all the colums which you use for joining the tables:

- id
- projects_id
- projectparams_id

This should speed it up already. (If not, you will have to be more specific about your use case and the database fields.)

Comment: Thanks, but navicat already create that indexes, and with indexes the time is 45 seconds. Without group statement it will be 8 millions of returned rows. I making mistake, but in where?

Comment: Seems quite ok for 8M rows ... is there a way to reduce the number of rows by some filter parameters?

Comment: I want to do that, but i don't know, how... I need to calculate price based on params. I can select only five params what will be cornered to price. So, if i need to filter my projects by price - i can do this.

But if i have one-two-three more filters - all will be erased.

Comment: Please see the other discussion ... I think the solution is there :)